# getorgchart library: how can I put button/link on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, orgchart

I hope that someone can help me.
i would like to add some buttons with differents links on one image.
I would like to catch button events.

I'm really interested in code examples to do that.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: what you are looking is called a image map take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change the theme that you are using

Here is an example:

```
var image = '<a xlink:href="http://www.GetOrgChart.com/">';   
image += '<text width="330" x="3" y="20">click me</text>';
image += '</a>';

getOrgChart.themes.annabel.image += image;

$("#people").getOrgChart({
    theme: "annabel",
    primaryColumns: ["Name", "Link"],
    dataSource: [
        { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie"},
        { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field", Image: "http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart-1.1-demos/images/d-6.jpg"},
        { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson"}]
});
```

Try in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GetOrgChart/fYU4Y/)

Comment: Thanks,  but how can i get the Id of "Ava Field"(id=2) on "click me" action in your example ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a new thread with your question, because the current version is not wrapped in jquery, and cannot answer your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the Id of the box when you click you can use [renderBoxContentEvent](http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#renderBoxContentEvent) event

Here is an example:

```
$("#people").getOrgChart({  
    renderBoxContentEvent: function( sender, args ) {
        if (args.id == 2)
            args.boxContentElements.push('<a xlink:href="javascript: alert(' + args.id + ')"><text width="330" x="20" y="100">click me</text></a>');
    },
    dataSource: [
        { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie", Title: "CEO", Address: "MyAddress"},
        { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field", Title: "CTO", Phone: "+359 888 888 888"},
        { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson", Title: "CFO", Car: "BMW"}]
});
```

[Try in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GetOrgChart/s9NSR/)

Note that you have to download the new version GetOrgChart v 1.2

Comment: Bit of necromancy, but boxContentElements is gone.  Try `args.content.splice(args.content.length - 1, 0, linkContent); //adding as 2nd last element.  last element is group closure </g>`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a image map

here is a example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>

<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>

</body>
</html>
```